# Why wont a Normal map be produced?

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

[image: bake isnt perfect, but all it needed was to just be unwrapped]I have modelled a wheel and am trying to bake from high to low poly however nothing is being produced regardless of max ray distance, below are lo and hi polys: [![Nothing is produced[][image: []
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYVsw.png)

(Edit: Top image is the fixed solution)

[image]

[image]

Comment: if the faces that you're trying to bake are completely perpendicular to the faces that are baking, nothing will be baked, but maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the reply, here is the .blend file, modifiers might still be active in this file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/8jldm6b0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't unwrapped the low-poly, do it

Comment: Thank you, I didnt even bother to check if it was unwrapped haha, works fine now.

Comment: yes it happens  ;)